# Error when checking target: expected concatenate_1 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (851,)

Tags: python, keras, keras-layer

I have some dimentional issue with a keras concatenation. It seems that the output array of the model (None, 851) is different from the dimention requiered in the error message. Here what I get:

```
input_img = Input(shape=(32, 100, 1))

conv1 = Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size=(5, 5), strides=1, padding="same", activation="relu")(input_img)
maxpool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=None, padding='valid', data_format=None)(conv1)

conv2 = Conv2D(filters = 128, kernel_size=(5, 5), strides=1, padding="same", activation="relu")(maxpool1)
maxpool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=None, padding='valid', data_format=None)(conv2)

conv3 = Conv2D(filters = 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=1, padding="same", activation="relu")(maxpool2)
maxpool3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=None, padding='valid', data_format=None)(conv3)

conv4 = Conv2D(filters = 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=1, padding="same", activation="relu")(maxpool3)
conv5 = Conv2D(filters = 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=1, padding="same", activation="relu")(conv4)
flat1 = Flatten(data_format=None)(conv5)
dense1 = Dense(units = 4096, activation = "relu")(flat1)
dense2 = Dense(units = 4096)(dense1)

towers = [Dense(units = 37, activation='softmax')(dense2) for i in range (23)]
output = concatenate(towers, axis = -1)

char = Model(input=input_img, output=output)
```

[Here is the summary the model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEjUf.jpg)

When I try to fit my model, I get the following message : 
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected concatenate_1 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (851,)

I don't understand why concatenate_1 should have shape (1,) and not (851,) or (None,851)
The size of my target_train is (867, 851), so .

Has someone ever encounter this kind of error?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in your `target_train`, the desired outputs you intend to learn. The network has after the concatenation 23*37 -> 851 which in the summary is `(None, 851)` where `None` is the dynamic batch size.

You need to investigate how you are passing `target_train` to the `.fit` function. The model output is 851 but the training loop is giving 1 single target instead.